# JDBC - Transactions explanation

Tags: database, jdbc, transactions

Below I have a code fragment, which aims at inserting records into a table `publisher` using prepared statements:

```
publisher(
    publisherID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(100)
);

//....

try {
      pStmt.setInt(1, 123);
      pStmt.setString(2, “Springer”);
      pStmt.setString(3, “Berlin”);
      pStmt.executeUpdate();

      con.rollback();
      con.setAutoCommit(false);

      pStmt.setInt(1, 124);
      pStmt.setString(2, “Heyne”);
      pStmt.setString(3, “München”);
      pStmt.executeUpdate();

      pStmt.setInt(1, 123);
      pStmt.setString(2, “Forum”);
      pStmt.setString(3, “Leipzig”);
      pStmt.executeUpdate();

      con.commit();

} catch(SQLException e) {
      try {
}
      con.rollback();
      con.close();

} catch(SQLException e) {}
```

If this code is executed, only the record `(124,"Heyne","München")` will be successfully inserted (according to the book). Can someone explain to my why the third tuple `(123, "Forum", "Leipzig")` won't be inserted?

Comment: Have you tried running the code to see if it does what "the book" says it does?

Comment: The last two entries should both be inserted and made durable. If it doesn't, that is a serious bug in the database or driver used (or you have left out important parts of the code or initial setup of the database). Did you actually try to run it? Given the presence of fancy-quotes, which is a syntax error, I think you haven't tried it.